# C: The first element of a char cannot be detected

Tags: c, string

I am learning getting inputs from key board. I want the user create a or more strings from the input, each string is considered as a line, the program will not terminate until a specified char is pressed. Then store these strings to the buffer.

However, when I print out the buffer, the first few elements of the string are always missing. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    printf("Please type the string:\n");
    char buffer[1000];
    int c;
    while( (c = getchar()) != ' ' ) {
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        printf("The output string is: \n%s\n", buffer);
        if((c = getchar())== ' '){
            printf("A space is detected!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Please type the string:
abcdefg
The output string is: 
bcdefg

hijklmn
The output string is: 
jklmn

opqrst
The output string is: 
qrst


A space is detected!
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Which part did I go wrong? Any hints are very much appreciated.

Comment: I believe that when using getChar(), you efficiently remove the character from stdin buffer. Tell me if that helps so I'll make it an answer.See Jim Buck's answer for more complete explanations.

Comment: Yep, if I replace"c = getchar()) != ' ' "to another condition, it works, but what should I do if I wanna use getchar?

Comment: You can always put it in the first position of your array and check `buffer[0]` instead of additionnal `c` variable. On the second check, you would want to do it in buffer[1] instead... but that looks like a patch to me. o/ (fgets would have to know if you should do `fgets(buffer + 1, ...)` or `fgets(buffer + 2, ...)`)

Comment: I posted an answer detailing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is both `getchar()`, and `fgets` in your code are reading from `stdin`. Since you call `getchar()` first in your test, it was consuming the first character of your string, when you called it again, another character disappeared...

You don't need `getchar()` at all to end your loop. All you care about for breaking your loop as you have explained is whether the user enters a `space` as the first character. `fgets` does not skip leading whitespace, so any leading space entered by the user will be captured at the beginning of `buffer`. So to satisfy your loop-exit condition, all you need to do is check if the first character of `buffer` is a space.

How? The simple way is to just derererence `buffer`, e.g. `*buffer` returns the first character in `buffer`. How? In pointer notation, `buffer + 0` is the offset you want in buffer, so to get the character at that location, you dereference, e.g. `*(buffer + 0)`, which of course is just `*buffer`, which is the equivalent of `buffer[0]`.

So, putting it altogether, and getting rid of `getchar()`, and adding `strlen` to properly validate that the string fit in `buffer` and to get the location for the trailing `'\n'` read and included in `buffer` by `fgets` (which leaves you with the length of trimmed string as a benefit), you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1000   /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char buffer[MAXC] = "";   /* initialize strings zero (good practice) */

    for (;;) {              /* loop continually taking input */
        size_t len;         /* variable for buffer length */

        printf ("\nenter string: ");            /* prompt */

        if (!fgets (buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))   /* read input */
            break;          /* exit if user cancels input */
        len = strlen (buffer);                  /* get length */
        if (len && buffer[len-1] == '\n')   /* check if last char is \n */
            buffer[--len] = 0;              /* overwrite with nul-char */
        else {  /* otherwise string too long */
            fputs ("error: string too long.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        if (*buffer == ' ')     /* check if 1st char of buffer is ' ' */
            break;

        printf ("buffer: %s  (%zu chars)\n", buffer, len);  /* output */
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgetsspace

enter string: my dog has fleas
buffer: my dog has fleas  (16 chars)

enter string: my cat has none
buffer: my cat has none  (15 chars)

enter string:  bye
```

(**note:** a space was entered before `bye` above, e.g. `" bye"`)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

---

**Separating Words with `strtok`**

To separate each line into individual words you can use `strtok`. The first argument is the `buffer` (for the 1st call), the second parameter is a list of characters to use as delimeters between the words (e.g. if you want to separate on `space` include a space, to not include the `'.'` at the end of a sentence include that as well -- and include the `'\n'`). After the 1st call to `strtok` all subsequent calls to get the remaining words uses `NULL` in place of `buffer`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1000   /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */

int main (void) {

    char buffer[MAXC] = "";   /* initialize strings zero (good practice) */

    for (;;) {                  /* loop continually taking input */
        size_t len;             /* variable for buffer length */
        char *delim = " .\n",   /* delmiters for strtok */
            *p = buffer;        /* pointer to buffer for strtok */

        printf ("\nenter string: ");            /* prompt */

        if (!fgets (buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))   /* read input */
            break;          /* exit if user cancels input */
        len = strlen (buffer);                  /* get length */
        if (len && buffer[len-1] == '\n')   /* check if last char is \n */
            buffer[--len] = 0;              /* overwrite with nul-char */
        else {  /* otherwise string too long */
            fputs ("error: string too long.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }

        if (*buffer == ' ')     /* check if 1st char of buffer is ' ' */
            break;

        printf ("buffer: %s  (%zu chars)\n", buffer, len);  /* output */

        p = strtok (buffer, delim); /* 1st call to strtok uses buffer */
        while (p != NULL) {
            printf ("  %s\n", p);
            p = strtok (NULL, delim);   /* subsequent calls use NULL */
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** the original `buffer` is modified, so make a copy if you need to preserve the original)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgetsspace

enter string: my dog has fleas
buffer: my dog has fleas  (16 chars)
  my
  dog
  has
  fleas

enter string: my cat has none
buffer: my cat has none  (15 chars)
  my
  cat
  has
  none

enter string:  bye
```

Comment: it is helps a lot. I do have a further question. Is it possible to obtain each word respectively? For example:"my dog has fleas" I want to access each word one by one. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, just ask, I'm happy to help. Yes, you can either use `strtok`, or just walk a pointer down the string picking out words as you go. I'll add a short example.

Answer (score 0):

`getchar` swallows up a character. Your first iteration gets one character swallowed up by the initial call in the `while`, and then successive iterations get two characters swallowed up, one by the `getchar` you use to detect a space and then again the one in the `while`.

Comment: You are right about it. Thanks! What should I do if I want to improve it?

Comment: I guess you already got it in the marked answer, but you could just use `fgets` only and test for a space.. however, I think it assumes you still need to wait for someone to hit 'enter' before you can check it, so it's not identical to the original behavior. If you want your original behavior back, you can call `ungetc` after your `getchar` calls. It will push the character back after you 'get' it. In this way, your original behavior, minus the bugs, is retained.

Answer (score 0):

Answering in addition to my initial comment and the issue:

First, quoting myself:

> I believe that when using getChar(), you efficiently remove the character from stdin buffer.

As stated since then by other people, the problem is that your call to getchar function consume and input, efficiently removing it from stdin buffer.

See Jim Buck's answer for detailed informations on the precise behavior of your application.

Now, what should you do ?

First, the if inside the while loop is not necessary, and using your application right now must be pretty odd. Try doing :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    printf("Please type the string:\n");
    char buffer[1000];
    int c;
    while( (c = getchar()) != ' ' ) {
        fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
        printf("The output string is: \n%s\n", buffer);
    }
    printf("A space is detected!\n");
}
```

Instead to prevent unnecessary user inputs. Your loop is basically an infinite loop so there is no need to check at the end of every iteration if the loop should terminate, the `while` statement is already doing that pretty damn well. :P

Now, to prevent the input from being taken out of buffer, I would consider using the buffer's first element instead of "c" variable.

Like so :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
    printf("Please type the strings:\n");
    char buffer[1000];
    while( (buffer[0] = getchar()) != ' ' ) { // Now reads directly into buffer
        fgets(buffer + 1, sizeof(buffer), stdin); // + 1 prevents overriding the char we just read. 
        printf("The output string is: \n%s\n", buffer);
    }
    printf("A space is detected!\n");
}
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: You still have it all backwards. You do `while (fgets (buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) { if (*buffer == ' ') break; printf("The output string is: \n%s\n", buffer); }`  You don't need `getchar()`, just check the 1st character in `buffer`.

Comment: It is a good approach! I always think there is no indexes in C.